# Regular expression for replacing html tags based on its position in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

```
<p>some text is hrere</p>

<pre>
    <p> some more text is here </p>
</pre>

<p> some other text is here </p>
```

In the above sample string, I wanted to replace `<p> and </p>` tags which are outside the `<pre>` tag with `<br/>` tag and `<p> and </p>` tags which are inside `<pre>` tag with `\n`.
 What is the regular expression for this in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been said many times: [don't use regex to manipulate HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Parse your HTML into a DOM tree - especially easy if it's XHTML - and manipulate it that way.

Don't do this.

Comment: No, I wanted to do this anyway. Actually, I am using an editor to create tutorial and upload it to the server. But this editor is putting so many <p> tags in all the places including <pre> tag which I use to surround code blocks. Can you please some regular expression for the above example?

Comment: Is there anybody to answer this?